# Select Join 2 tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, How to get title and image_path

user

```
id | title
```

relation

```
id | image_id | user_id
```

images

```
id | image_path
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: These 3 tables doesn´t make sense.

Comment: @LenglBoy seems pretty clear it's a simple m-m relation image_id is the fk for images.id and user_id is fk for user.id

Comment: @BigMike I know but you can´t say that users got same profile pictures so that this could be an m-m (only if there are only system pictures but no one do this...)

Comment: I guess real tables have more columns (and hopefully better names). Why are we assuming the image being a profile picture ? For such simple scenarios (1-1) I would've just add an image_id column to user table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some like

```
select u.title, i.image_path
from user u
join relation r on u.id = r.user_id
join images i on r.image_id = i.id
```